# How can I set this alignment?

Tags: html, css

"New" & "Here is News". They won't be on the same alignment horizontally.
How can I put them in the same line?

Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/CtCuk/2/

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="top_page">
    <div class='container-general'>
        <div class="annouce-row">    
            <div class='title'>
                New
            </div>
            <div class='annoucement'>
                Here is News
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top_page{
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto 20px;
}

.annouce-row{
    width: 800px;
}

.title {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(123, 0, 218);
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 70px;
}

.announcement {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: rgb(0, 174, 218);
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: You're going to confuse yourself if you only sometimes misspell "announce".

Answer (score 3):

```
.annouce-row div {
    width: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CtCuk/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CtCuk/9/ please take a look at this. Why "Here is News" is folded? I want it straight, and it should only folds when width is narrowed down. Could you customize it?

Answer (score 1):

```
.annouce-row
{
     overflow:hidden;
}
.title
{
    float:left;
}
.annoucement
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:20px; //Change this as much as it suits you
}
```

There is no div with class `.announce`, its `.annoucement`, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/cqh49/

Comment: Thanks!! However can't you put text align in annoucement? I added text-align: left; into annoucement, but it won't work:(

Comment: There's an error in the CSS of your Fiddle, the div has a class `.annoucement` not `.annouce`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put:
    `float:left;`
in your css properties? [image]

Comment: Thanks. but it seems it won't take text-align:left; in annoucement :(